# How <T> is dealing here with String and Integer

Tags: java, generics

I am not able to understand how T is taking Integer and String. As here in display function T is dealing with both Integer and String. How this code is working?

```
class firstBase {
   <T> void display(T give_num, T give_String) {
        System.out.println("The given number is = " 
                           + give_num + " The given String is  =  " + give_String);

        System.out.println("The class of given number is = " 
                           + give_num.getClass() + 
                           " The class of given_String is = "+give_String.getClass());
    }
 }


public class testanonymous {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        firstBase fb = new firstBase();
        fb.display(100, "xyz");
    }
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile - `The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) T`

Comment: Everything that you need is documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Comment: You said "How is this code working?". Have you seen it working? Show us output using [IDEONE](http://www.ideone.com).

Comment: My confusion here is at a time either Integer or String will be taken into consideration, but here how both Integer and String are working.

Comment: Hey i have corrected the error. Please look into it again.

Answer (score 5):

You're invoking the *raw* form of the method, which is basically equal to

```
void display(Object give_num, Object give_String)
```

Here, both of the arguments you provide fit, because `100` is autoboxed to `Integer` (which is a subclass of `Object`) and "xyz" is a `String` (which is a subclass of `Object`)

To use Generics correctly, you have to do:

```
fb.<String>display(100, "xyz");
```

or

```
fb.<Integer>display(100, "xyz");
```

In both cases, you'll note that the code doesn't compile, because the compiler will be aware of your intent to replace `T` with `Integer`/`String` at Runtime, but the parameter types are not of the same provided type.

Comment: A small aside but `100` is autoboxed into an `Integer` first. In this case this isn't important but if you have different overloads of the same method, things can become tricky.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I just added the note. Thanks :)

Comment: Hey code is working fine. There was an error which i have corrected.

Comment: I wouldn't call it the "raw form of the method" - that sounds confusingly similar to "raw type", which is unrelated. More accurately, the compiler is inferring `Object` for `T`.